# How to parse a Json with Go

Tags: sql, arrays, go, psql

Have tis code:

```
type Foo struct {
  field string
  Value string  

  }

type Guyy struct {
  info Foo
  
  }

func main() {
    GuyJson := `{"info":[{"field":"phone","value":"11111-11111"},{"field":"date","value":"05072001"},{"field":"nationality","value":"american"},{"field":"dni","value":"000012345"}]}`
    var Guy Guyy    
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(GuyJson), &Guy)
    fmt.Printf("%+v", Guy)
}
```

When compile I get

```
{info:{field: Value:}}
```

How can I get the field and value of nationality?

Comment: Are you connecting to Postgres using e.g. [pq](https://github.com/lib/pq), or just parsing the psql output? If it's the latter, why?

Comment: *"Is it possible to get the natiolanity value?"* -- Yes, it is possible. If you have tried it but failed please show the code, show your effort. If you haven't tried it, why not? And do note that that, does not look like a "psql array", rather, it looks like a value of the PostgreSQL `jsonb` type, and parsing json is, generally, extremely simple in Go and you'll find thousands of posts about that right here on stackoverflow. I suggest you do a bit of research and write some code before asking.

Comment: I've assigned the data from the row, pretending to have already executed the query

Comment: First problem is that your struct fields are unexported (they start with a lowercase letter), such fields are not accessible to other package for modification and therefore the `encoding/json` package cannot modify and instance of `*Guy`. To export the fields, change their first letter to uppercase.

Comment: Second problem, your `info` field is of type `Foo` which is a struct type, however the `"info"` field in the json contains an array. The two types, struct & array, are incompatible. If you want to unmarshal a json array you should use a Go slice instead of a struct. For example `Info []Foo` should be the field in `Guy`.

Comment: Third: when using a function that can return an error, you should never ignore that error. e.g. `json.Unmarshal` returns an error that you should assign to a variable and then check whether it is `nil` or not and if yes the calling function should exit.

Comment: Once you have that down, you can loop over the `Info` field, which is now a slice, and check each element's `Field` value whether or not it is `"nationality"`, and when you get a match then you can take the element's `Value` value.

Comment: This is just a trash code for just testing.
I've changed my code and now when I do
`fmt.Printf("%+v", Guy.Info[2])` i get `{Field:nationality Value:american}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change struct to slice (`info` represent  list of structs)
2. You `struct field` must be `exported` ([Marshal](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal), [Unmarshal](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshal), [A Tour of GO](https://tour.golang.org/basics/3))

> Struct values encode as JSON objects. Each exported struct field becomes a member of the object, using the field name as the object key, unless the field is omitted...

```
type Guyy struct {
  Info []Foo //  exported slice 
}
```

<kbd>[PLAYGROUND](https://play.golang.org/p/bO4nQ3_CyvI)</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

```
var Guy Guyy
var f interface{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(GuyJson), &f)

m := f.(map[string]interface{})

foomap := m["info"]
v := foomap.([]interface{})

for _, fi := range v {
    vi := fi.(map[string]interface{})

    var f Foo
    f.Field = vi["field"].(string)
    f.Value = vi["value"].(string)

    if f.Field == "nationality" {
        fmt.Println(f.Field, "was found to be", f.Value)
    }

    Guy.Info = append(Guy.Info, f)
}

fmt.Println(Guy)
```

> Refer this link for complete code -> https://play.golang.org/p/vFgpE0GNJ7K